# Can I change DataTable View to Gallery View?

Tags: datatable, view

I have a datatable with rows and columns and I have change it to card view. But I want to view it in Gallery mode as some of the td wont be shown on the gallery. Is it possible?

Comment: This question is probably too broad and high-level for anyone to be able to help you. You can show us a [mre] of what you are attempting to do, and present the _specific_ problem you are facing. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.